# Issue deploying fileLogs in Linux Diagnostic Agent

Tags: azure, monitoring

I am trying to update a linux diagnostic file's json to add fileLog.

A copy of the json file can be found [HERE](https://gist.github.com/Genysys/5f66064af0c73276a6f8ec58d62c27ac).

The issue is I can't seem to find them in the storage table even after creating the table in the storage account.

I would appreciate any pointers on this

## Update:

I have updated the json file and a copy can be found [HERE](https://gist.github.com/Genysys/26eb9d82dafdc780f2a18373edc09c9e)

I still cannot view the logs in my storage account.

When I check the extensions, I get the following error:

[image]

This points to an error with my json file. I will appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three things I see wrong with your JSON file:

1. The ***StorageAccount*** name is invalid.  A storage account cannot have uppercase characters.  Details [here][1].
2. The ***resourceId*** is invalid.  Instead of "resourceId": `"/subscriptions//providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SANDBOX"`, it should be `"resourceId": "/subscriptions/<YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID>/resourceGroups/<YOUR VM RESOURCE GROUP>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SANDBOX"`.
3. The ***fileLogs*** section appears to be nested in your ***ladCfg*** section.  It should be at the same level as the ***ladCfg***.

There may be other problems but these caught my eye.

Comment: Thanks Rick. 1 & 2 were my attempts to obfuscate data. I have taken reccomendations from 3 but not sure where this log files are meant to turn up in azure as the table I created (Parity Logs) is empty